# ASP.NET server tag with colon?

Tags: asp.net, markup, server-tags, servertag

I searched all around, but could not find any reasonable explanation.

I found `<%:` tag in one of the projects. It works like the `<%=` tag.

I could not find any description on this tag I only found that `<%:` and `<%=` are the same.

So the question popped out, why could there be two different tags with same functionality? I think there should be some difference.

Could you please clarify it for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) it is a new feature introduced in ASP.NET 4. It is used to automatically HTML Encode the output.

I suggest to read the full blog post, to see how it works ;)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find that post unfortunately on my own :)

Answer (score 2):

`<%:` Performs a HTML Encode on the string you are writing out

Scott Hanselman suggests thinking about the equals sign being closed - like a gate (side on view). He talks about it in this video

[ASP.NET MVC 2: Ninja Black Belt Tips](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Ninja-Black-Belt-Tips-by-Scott-Hanselman)

Answer (score 1):

`<% %>` are [Embedded Code Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178135%28vs.80%29.aspx)

```
and
```

`<%= %>` are used to 
[Display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx) content from web page.

Moreover you can find all the details about [ASP.NET Page Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h.aspx) from here.

Hope this helps!!